# How to add authorization roles for social login users on Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am a committee member of a charity with G Suite.  I put our small membership database which was an excel spreadsheet into an Oracle Apex app, and also allowed login from our G Suite domain - internal rather than external.

Currently, only committee members have domain email addresses but I want to allow all to view but only some to edit so random elderly committee members don't destroy the database.

Is there an easy method to assign roles to members who login via social logins?

Comment: Are those people signing in differently using a different application to do so? Then sure! What other ways can you safely identify these people?

Comment: They'd be just using the default application that is created by Apex. I could create specific logins for each person and presumably set authorisation per log in, but the committee changes yearly so I'm looking for something easier which is why I used social login by our domain

Comment: Does G Suite give you the ability to assign users to roles and get those roles during authentication? If not, you could always do that on your side with two simple tables: roles and user_roles.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll look at that